# Cannot insert value from texfield on specific id

Tags: php, sql

Hello I have a problem in my query. I want to insert a value in SQL table on a specific specific id.
In detail a have a table that that each column has a textfield and the values of each textfield must inserted in a specific row of SQL table. The **uid** is a foreign key of table 'candidate', it  is the primary key of a table that contains each user details.
the code is the following:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['uid']) && $_REQUEST['uid'] && isset($_POST['add']))
  {     
   $comments_manager =($_POST['comments_manager']);
    $uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
    //$comments_manager  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments_manager']);



$sql   = "INSERT INTO candidate (comments_manager) 
         VALUES ('$comments_manager')
        WHERE uid = ".intval($uid)
        ;
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$query){

             die('Invalid query:' . mysql_error());
         }
           else{
          header('Location: ../manager/test3.php');
```

This is a column of a table

```
                print "<td>";
                print '<form action="" method="POST">';
                print '<input type="hidden" name="uid" value='.$row['uid'].' />';
                print '<input type="text"  name="comments_manager" value='.$comments_manager.' />';
                print '<br><input type="submit" name="add" value="add">';
                                    print '</form>';
                                    print "</td>";
```

`
     When I submit a value in textfield a take this message *Invalid query:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version.  for the right syntax to use near ' WHERE uid = 63' at line 2* What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INSERT` is for creating new rows, not updating existing rows, so it doesn't make sense to have a `WHERE` clause. To modify an existing row, you use `UPDATE`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE candidate
        SET comments_manager = '$comments_manager'
        WHERE uid = " . intval($uid);
```

Comment: Ok i didn'd realise  the difference! Thank you!! You help me to solve a problem that days I couldn't!Thank you